# I'm using router for the first time.. How can I make route to render first component automatically when it's opened?

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom, router

When I go to my server for example to, http://localhost:3000/my_app/
It wouldn't render "Home". My page will only show me the navigation component.
but when I click the Home button on navigation bar, then it renders the "Home" component.
I am not sure how to make it to render "Home" by default just automatically when I connect to the server.. How can I fix this problem?

This is code of App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./routes/Home";
import Recipes from "./routes/Recipes";
import About from "./routes/About";
import Navigation from "./components/Navigation";
import ScrollToTop from "./components/ScrollToTop";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navigation />
        <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Home} />
        <Route path="/recipes" component={Recipes} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <ScrollToTop />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is code of Home.js

```
import React from "react";
import main_img from "../img/cocktail_main.jpg";
import "./Home.css";

function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="home_container">
      <img src={ main_img } className="main_img" alt="main_img" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: Why is there `my_app` in your url ? you don't seem to declare that as base route of your app.

Comment: Can you share the nav component code? What is the home link pointing to?

Answer (score 0):

First wrap your routes inside Switch component in order to force it to render the first match. then, try using Redirect component if you want to render a specific component for other routers. Pls read this part of the documentation for [Switch](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch) and [Redirect](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect)

```
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Home} />
        <Route path="/recipes" component={Recipes} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Redirect to="/" />
    </Switch>
```